# Giving user friendly exception messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, formview

I am using the following code to handle Delete exceptions in my Formview. The trouble is I want to give the user a simple explanation should an error occur but I can't find a way to do so easily. I should say I'm new to ASP.NET. In the past I would have used an ERROR_NO to trap errors but I can't find the equivalent here. I can see that e.Exception.Message gives the error info but I can't give this to the user!...

EG: e.Exception.Message gives "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_users_offices". The conflict occurred in database "xyz", table "dbo.Users", column 'OfficeID'. The statement has been terminated."

Is there a way to identify this exception and trap it to display something like, "This Office cannot be deleted because dependent Users exists." for example?

My relevant code behind is:

```
    protected void fv_OnItemDeleted(Object sender, FormViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception == null)
        {
            if (e.AffectedRows == 1)
            {
                lblMessage.Text="Record deleted successfully.";
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "An error occurred during the delete operation.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text=e.Exception.Message;
            e.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }

        UserMessage.Visible = true; // Display Error message to user
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910197/user-friendly-error-messages-when-removing-row-with-foreign-key-reference-constr and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944559/how-to-manipulate-sqlexception-message-into-user-friendly-message

Answer (score 1):

You may check the exception type and return messages to user according to exception type. Something like;

```
protected void fv_OnItemDeleted(Object sender, FormViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Exception == null)
    {
        if (e.AffectedRows == 1)
        {
            lblMessage.Text="Record deleted successfully.";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "An error occurred during the delete operation.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text=e.Exception.Message; 
        if(e.Exception.GetType() == typeof(System.StackOverflowException))
             lblMessage.Text = "Some stackoverflowexception occured, report to admin etc."       
        if(e.Exception.GetType() == typeof(System.ArgumentNullException))
             lblMessage.Text = "Some argument exception occured"

        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

    UserMessage.Visible = true; // Display Error message to user
}
```

Comment: Please note that if it is no stackoverflow or argumentnullexception, that it still displays the detailed message which should be hidden for normal users.

Comment: @JPHellemons I agree with you, a default message can be displayed to user, instead of displaying the original exception message if this is the case.

Comment: Ok thanks all for your efforts . It seems there is no easy way. What happened to good old error numbers??!!